# How to convert Int to hex string?

Tags: type-conversion, haxe

Is it possible to convert integer to 6 digit hex code? In AS3 I had native API

```
var color:uint = 0xFF00FF;
trace("Color #" + color.toString(16)); //Color #ff00ff
```

Does Haxe have such functionality in standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringTools.hex()`
http://api.haxe.org/StringTools.html#hex